# Android prevent to go back to the previous Activity

Tags: android

How can prevent when user click back, only back to one page before the login `Activity`. If hit the last page before login `Activity`, then exit the app. Now, if i click go back it will show the login page and need login again. Once user login, unless they click logout button, otherwise don't show login `Activity`.

Any idea on this?
Thank you.

Comment: show your code for better help

Comment: Use shared preference to store user login session. once user login finish login activity and from all activity check if user is logged in then redirect to dashboard (whatever screen). and when logout clear that session.

Answer (score 17):

If you would like to simply prevent the back button to navigate back to your login `Activity`, you could just set the `android:noHistory` attribute to `true` for your login `Activity` in your Manifest.

Something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Always open your activity after splash screen. Decide which activity you want to navigate the user using the stored login data. To store login data use shared preferences. But at the time of login, after logging in if user clicks back, user will be navigated back to login activity. So once the user successfully logged in clear the activities on stack while navigating the user to main/home activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

use shared preference to achieve this:

On Login successful, write a shared preference like below

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("your_preference_name", 0); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("LoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();
```

Also to prevent other activities to come back to Login page, we should finish the login page before moving to target screen

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, TargetClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

Also whenever u come back to the application, u can directly move ur user to Home page by this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("your_preference_name", 0);
boolean isLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false);

if(isLoggedIn )
{
    //Go directly to Homescreen.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you start an activity from Login Activity then after StartActicity(), finish the login activity by calling finish() function.

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()` in your login activity when opening the next activity after user logs in. And as someone pointed out that you can store your authtoken in `sharedPreference` once user logs in and use that data to maintain the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way too, via playing with the launchmode of the android manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourPackageName.LoginActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do login and Intent than call in login Activity

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Kotlin, this is how to go about it:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
```